# Get all body elements without the div using a query selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to get all body elements in a query without divs elements, here is my code,

```
body = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
elements = body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, '*')
```

but with this, I get all the elements, and I want the ones that are not div elements.

Is possible make this with one query?

Comment: Try `*:not(div)`. Works in CSS selectors, not sure, it’ll work here…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following:

```
elements = body.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[not(self::div)]')
```